# Help understanding eBooks sales

Tags: amazon, sales, statistics

[This statistics page](https://www.statista.com/outlook/213/100/ebooks/worldwide#market-revenue) states that worldwide eBook in 2017 totaled $13B. It also states that US sales were ~ $6B.

On the other hand, [this report from Author Earnings](https://web.archive.org/web/20180321235631/http://authorearnings.com/report/february-2017/) cites US sales in 2017 as being $3B.

**This is nearly a 100% margin of error.** It would be very much appreciated if somebody could help rectify this error. Which, if either of them, is accurate? How can I obtain more accurate eBook market value statistics?